# Visual Studio is falling apart on me?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol

I have a problem that I hope can be fixed.  I have been working on a project in VS 2010 - and it seems things are falling apart faster than I can fix them.  I have not changed how I am coding or using the designer from the previous months...  Here are some screen shots - perhaps someone can help me figure out what's going on here?  I know this is rather vague - but I'm pulling my hair out, and maybe someone else has been in this boat!

These are from the TabControl craping out on me, an things are missing off my ToolStrips too!

HELP!  -- Andrew

[image: VS sucks 1]
[image]

**UPDATE**

The above issues are fixed, and I was able to use the designer for a limited time - however after a build I now get the errors below...  I have removed bin / obj folders to no avail.

```
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: 
Object does not match target type
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] args)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

**SO NOW** I'm trying to figure out this half of the problem...

Comment: It would appear I have lost everything in StatusStrip containers as well...

Comment: I am downloading SP1 for VS 2010 - not sure how I didn't already have it, but I'm getting it now and will post back when done, to determine if it fixes any issues.

Comment: @CharithJ Yes, this is all in Design Mode :(

Comment: How are you editing the designer file?

Comment: It seems that having a StatusStrip within a TabControl was the root of all my issues.  I reverted back to a previous version of the [file].Designer.cs and have pieced back together my day's work.  I sure hope I don't run into a similar problem later.

Thanks for all the input -- Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some times below helps to catch design time errors. [Reference](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/289686/exception-of-type-system-componentmodel-design-exceptioncollection-was-thrown)

> 1) Start a second instance of visual studio
>
> 2) go the the Tools menu, "Attach to process", select the 'devenv.exe'
>   process, and click the 'attach' button.
>
> 3) In the Debug/Exceptions menu, 
>   [image]
>   Turn on exception catching when first thrown (in the Debug->Exceptions menu).
>
> 4) Open the designer with the debugger attached.
>
> 5) The second visual studion will break on your error.

Comment: Humm, I'll give that a shot after SP1 installs - it's a rather large 600 megabyte update....

Comment: The most likely cause is a custom control or user-control is initializing and an exception is occuring. This answer is the quickiest way to find the problem.

Comment: Was not using any custom controls, FYI.

Comment: I did per your suggestion, however it's not catching the type of error I have posted under the 'UPDATE' above... Useful information though on how to connect to already-running processes! Thanks -- Andrew

Comment: Well, the last thing you could is them. Comment all of their event binding and uncomment one by one to find the error. If you have anything in the Load events those may be the reason. What I normally would do is move all the initializations to a public init() method and call them programmatically rather than firing on an Load event.

Comment: Get rid of the TabControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged event and see.

Comment: I assume you mean in the [file].Designer.cs file?  Oh boy - that's ~ 3k lines to go though...  I'm going home for the night and may have to try that in the morning - 14 hours into today and my brain is dead.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @CharithJ Got it!  Looks like for whatever reason setting the `Text = "Some Value";` for a `ToolStripTextBox` was causing the problem, this time!  Now I **know** I set that though the designer - but at this point - whatever.  I'll see if it breaks again in the morning.  **Thanks everyone for your help!**

Comment: Pleased you sorted it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does your TabControl have many tabs? Older versions of WinForms had some bugs when tabs could not visually fit into the TabControl width.

First save your original source somewhere safe, then try deleting tab-by-tab to see if this changes anything. If it does, then at least you have diagnosed the problem and you may have a chance to redesign your UI with fewer tabs...

Comment: Not what I would consider very many - 6 in total - and it should be the latest version of WinForms - just created the entire project two months ago, targeting the .NET 3.5 platform.

Comment: @Fuginator Is your TabControl too narrow for all 6 tabs to visually fit into it (while in form designer)?

Comment: Everything fits with an inch or so remaining on the rightmost side.

Answer (score 1):

You've removed or changed the type a property from one of your derived or usercontrol classes that you dropped onto a form. When you dropped it on, it serialized all the properties into the form. Now when you are trying to open the form it's dying because the properties in the serialized version no longer matches the actual class.
Unfortunately I don't know how to fix this beyond restoring the removed or changed property.

Comment: This sounds very possible - the only custom item I'm using is a spell-checker component - and I only have one version of it.  See updated error above.  And as always, thanks for the input and help!