# [File].Designer.cs corrupting self - Designer hell

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a winforms application that I am writing in C# -  in Visual Studio 2010.  I have one specific form that keeps corrupting itself every other day or so - according to TFS, it looks like most of the file is re-written by the designer when I have made only the smallest changes. (location of buttions, etc.)  Things fall off strips, toolbars, etc. as well as errors just trying to use the designer.  See my other post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264598/visual-studio-is-falling-apart-on-me). (Thought I figured this out, but I guess not)

Here is an example piece of code that goes missing - when I put it back in, it takes it back out when I save the file.  The code was generated by the designer in a previous file version.

```
this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.tssEmployeeName,
        this.tssLoadTime,
        this.tssSpring,
        this.tssHomeLocation,
        this.tssTotal,
        this.tssDue});
```

Is there any way of 're-generating' the [file].Designer.cs file?  Or should I bite the bullet and re-do this form?  (pain with over 100 components on this one...)  It's the only form I have a problem with out of the 35 or so in the project.

VS 2010 w\ SP1.

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, I read your other post (VS 2010 falling apart)  a couple of days ago, what did you find when you attached to process and debugged the design time GUI error? It seems this form had a problem that is getting worse. Try copying all the code.cs & designer.cs content to a txt file (as a basic sanitize if any text is corrupt) then create a new form with a different name and tell us if that form loses designer code on saves?

Comment: @Jeremy Nothing ever came up in the debugger, after attaching to the process and selecting both options.  Just the same type of errors in the Designer itself.  Will try copy / paste (txt file) / make new forms and let you guys know.  _Thanks for the help_ Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before, although I'm not sure if my issues were exactly the same.

Try putting a handful of problem controls, such as your StatusStrip control and its children, into separate User Controls. Then add those User Controls to the main form instead. At the very least, you can prevent the designer from rewriting those controls.